# Best way to get records from one table based on other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `twitter_followers` and `twitter_friends`. Both tables have many columns (`id`, `user_id`, `twitter_id`, etc.). For a single `user_id` the number of rows in both tables can be more than 100000 records.

I want to retrieve records from `twitter_friends` of `user` in the following way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM twitter_friends 
WHERE user_id=1 
AND twitter_id NOT IN (SELECT twitter_id FROM twitter_followers WHERE user_id=1)
```

This query is okay for small set of data, but can any one help me to get large no of data (preferably in a few seconds)?

Comment: no success yet can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

MySql's subquery performance is shockingly bad. I would suggest using a JOIN statement.

Like:

```
Select Friends.*, Followers.twitter_id
from twitter_friends as Friends
LEFT JOIN twitter_followers as Followers
 on Friends.USER_ID = Followers.USER_ID
where friends.user_id=1 AND followers.twitter_id is null;
```